# How to insert a primary key into another table with a trigger after inserting it in the first table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

My database contains two tables; each table has the primary key on column `ID`.

The first table, `tbl_Person` also has a foreign key which references the second table, `tbl_Address`:

```
tbl_Person           tbl_Address
+----+------+        +----+---------+
| ID | Name |        | ID | Address |
+----+------+        +----+---------+
| 1  | Jim  |  --->  | 1  |  .....  |
| 2  | Tim  |        | 2  |  .....  |
| 3  | Kim  |        | 3  |  .....  |
+----+------+        +----+---------+
```

I am now wondering how I could create a trigger, which inserts the `ID` of a newly inserted person into the second table, `tbl_Address` and set all other attributes of `tbl_Address` to NULL.

My current trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_Person 
ON tbl_Person
BEFORE INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ID INT
 
   SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   FROM tbl_Person

   INSERT INTO tbl_Address (ID)
   VALUES (@ID)
END
```

Comment: *"The first table, tbl_Person also has a foreign key which references the second table, tbl_Address"* Do you not mean that `tbl_Address` has a `FOREIGN KEY` that references `tbl_person`?

Comment: Yeah I meant that

Comment: Did you notice that Larnu fixed two serious flaws in your original code as well? Do NOT assume a single row is inserted (or updated or deleted) when a trigger executes. Nor does TSQL support a "before" trigger. But you still another serious issue. You are inserting "fake" rows into tbl_address that have no actual information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the `inserted` pseudo-object:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_CreatePersonAddress ON dbo.Tbl_Person
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Address(ID) --Should this not be PersonID?
    SELECT ID
    FROM inserted;

END;
GO
```

Comment: Should check for an empty inserted table and do nothing.